# FOSElasticaBundle indexing hidden objects

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have installed FOSElasticaBundle, my config `fos_elastica.yml` is as follows:

```
 fos_elastica:
 clients:
     default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
 indexes:
     test:
         client: default
         index_name : %elastica_index_name%
         types:
             exhibition:
                 mappings:
                     name : { boost: 100 }
                     company: { boost: 9 }
                     directions: { boost: 8}
                     tags: { boost: 7 }
                     description : { boost: 6 }
                     status : ~
                 persistence:
                     driver: orm
                     model: Test\MainBundle\Entity\Exhibition
                     finder: ~
                     provider: ~
                     listener:
                         is_indexable_callback: "isPublic"
```

On persist `is_indexable_callback` works. But when I run `fos:elastica:populate`, the index is created even for hidden objects.

How can I index just active object? Maybe using analyzer or something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify:

```
provider:
    query_builder_method: createSearchIndexQueryBuilder
```

and then add method into related `Entity\Repository`:

```
public function createSearchIndexQueryBuilder()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
    //->write_magic_here;

    return $qb;
}
```